# Neo4j 1.9: Multiple Matching or Merging

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**NEO4J 1.9.x**

I am trying to create a query statement that retrieves user posts. Currently I am only pulling posts that are created through a friendship connection. This works fine, however, I want to insert posts created by the requestor as well. The result is a feed that contains the author's posts as well as their friends posts. I can not, for the life of me, figure out how to do it.

```
START 
    requestor=node:node_auto_index(UID = '19')
MATCH 
    (requestor)-[:Are_Connected]-(friends)-[:Wrote|Shared]-(post)<-[?:Included_With]-(link)
WHERE 
    post.type! = "Post"
RETURN DISTINCT post, link
ORDER BY post.createdzulu DESC
```

This returns exactly what I need. Trying this...

```
START 
    requestor=node:node_auto_index(UID = '19')
MATCH 
    (requestor)-[:Are_Connected]-(friends)-[:Wrote|Shared]-(post)<-[?:Included_With]-(link),
    (requestor)-[:Wrote|Shared]-(post)<-[?:Included_With]-(link)
WHERE 
    post.type! = "Post"
RETURN DISTINCT post, link
ORDER BY post.createdzulu DESC
```

... returns nothing since the Matching here is an **AND** not an **OR**

I could solve this programmatically by doing two queries and merging the results, but that is a bit too hackish for my taste. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use union

```
START 
    requestor=node:node_auto_index(UID = '19')
MATCH 
    (requestor)-[:Are_Connected]-(friends)-[:Wrote|Shared]-(post)<-[?:Included_With]-(link)
WHERE 
    post.type! = "Post"
RETURN DISTINCT post, link
ORDER BY post.createdzulu DESC
UNION
MATCH
    (requestor)-[:Wrote|Shared]-(post)<-[?:Included_With]-(link)
WHERE 
    post.type! = "Post"
RETURN DISTINCT post, link
ORDER BY post.createdzulu DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't use that since it was introduced in NEO4J in 2.0, I'm working with 1.9

Comment: so as a dirty work u can make a self relation to every requester node then use this
(requestor)-[:Are_Connected*0..1]-(friends)-[:Wrote|Shared]-(post)<-[?:Included_With]-(link)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know and understand, i think i had a similar problem with a query i wanted to do. The last thing i remember doing was using the where clause for both matches.

```
START 
    requestor=node:node_auto_index(UID = '19')
WHERE 
    ((requestor)-[:Are_Connected]-(friends)-[:Wrote|Shared]-(post)<-[?:Included_With]-(link)
    OR
    (requestor)-[:Wrote|Shared]-(post)<-[?:Included_With]-(link))
AND WHERE 
    post.type! = "Post"
RETURN DISTINCT post, link
ORDER BY post.createdzulu DESC
```

I am not sure about efficency, since in my tests with neo4j the match clause is usually faster but you could try.

Hope it helps